# Visible faces of a polyhedron $P$ on a path of viewpoints on the unit sphere looking at the center of $P$

Tags: geometry, computer-science, 3d, computational-geometry

Let $P$ be an opaque polyhedron.

Assuming [*parallel projection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection), let's define a **viewpoint** to be a point on the unit sphere around the center of $P$.

Let's say that two viewpoints $v_1$ and $v_2$ are **topological equivalent**, if

1. we see the same set $F$ of faces from $v_1$ and $v_2$
2. there is a path $p$ of viewpoints between $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that we see $F$ from all viewpoints on $p$ (i.e. there is no viewpoint on $p$ such that we see any other face not contained in $F$ and no face from $F$ will disappear)

> We can prove that if $P$ is convex, any two viewpoints which satisfy (1.) are topological equivalent, i.e. they satisfy (2.) too.

Does anyone know a simple example of a non-convex $P$ such that there are two viewpoints satisfying (1.) but not (2.)?

Comment: You assume that your polyhedron is opaque, isn't it ? (not a wire-frame polyhedron model)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, indeed.